# Is there an "elegant" way to test that an attribute value starts with a letter?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I need to test whether an attibute value starts with a letter. If it doesn't I'll prefix it with "ID_" so it will be a valid id type of attribue value. 
I currently have the following (testing that the value does not start with a number - I know these attribute values will only start with a letter or number), but I am hoping there is an more elegant way:

```
<xsl:if test="not(starts-with(@value, '1')) and not(starts-with(@value, '2')) and not(starts-with(@value, '3')) and not(starts-with(@value, '4')) and not(starts-with(@value, '5')) and not(starts-with(@value, '6')) and not(starts-with(@value, '7')) and not(starts-with(@value, '8')) and not(starts-with(@value, '9')) and not(starts-with(@value, '0')) ">
```

I'm using XSLT 1.0.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: String handling operations in XSLT 1.0 are often possible, but they are rarely elegant.

Comment: @Michael - true, but these answer are definitely *more* elegant than what I had!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Use**:

```
not(number(substring(@value,1,1)) = number(substring(@value,1,1)) )
```

**Or use**:

```
not(contains('0123456789', substring(@value,1,1)))
```

**Finally, this may be the shortest XPath 1.0 expression to verify your condition**:

```
not(number(substring(@value, 1, 1)+1))
```

Comment: Great answers - +1. The third and shortest way is a nice twist. Would never have thought of that.

Comment: @Jacqueline: Yes, XPath is an amazing language and becomes even more so in version 2.0 and 3.0.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit shorter, if not exactly elegant or obvious:

```
<xsl:if test="not(number(translate(substring(@value, 1, 1),'0','1')))">
```

The basic idea is to test whether the first character is a digit.  The `translate()` call is needed because `0` and `NaN` both evaluate to `false` and we need `0` to be treated as `true` inside of the `not()` call.

Comment: +1 for a great answer. And thanks for the info about '0' returning false.

Answer (score 4):

```
<xsl:if test="string(number(substring(@value,1,1)))='NaN'">
```

1. Use `substring()` to snag the first character from the `@value` value
2. Use the `number()` function to evaluate that character

   1. If the character is a number, it will return a number
   2. If the character is not a number it will return `NaN`
3. Use the `string()` function to evaluate that as a string and check to see if it is `NaN` or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:if test="string-length(number(substring(@value,1,1))) > 1">
```

1. Use the `substring()` function to snag the first character from the `@value` value
2. Use the `number()` function to evaluate that character

   1. If the character is a number, it will return a number
   2. If the character is not a number it will return `NaN`
3. Use `string-length()` to evaluate whether it was greater than 1 (not a number)