# XSL - is there a way to check the first 3 letters of a value and if true, do this?

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am new to XSL and have read a few tutorials on how it works.  I have already read this: [Is there an "elegant" way to test that an attribute value starts with a letter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984831/is-there-an-elegant-way-to-test-that-an-attribute-value-starts-with-a-letter) which is basically what I wanted but It is not working when I am trying it.  the purpose of this Is if the value of @extention.name has the first 2 letters as "MM", I want it to display @extention.name.  If not I wantit to display @extention.length.   Im sure it is something simple but anyways here is what I have.

```
            </td>
            <xsl:if test="@extension.name not contains('MM', substring(@value,1,1))" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
              <xsl:value-of select="@extension.name" />
            </xsl:if>
            <td style="text-align:center;">
            <xsl:value-of select="@extension.length" />
            </td>
```

Comment: Please show us a **reproducible** example, including an input and a complete (if minimal) stylesheet. Code snippets taken out of context are not helpful - see: [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the purpose of this Is if the value of @extention.name has the first 2
>   letters as "MM", I want it to display @extention.name. If not I wantit
>   to display @extention.length.

For this purpose you should be using:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="starts-with(@extension.name, 'MM')">
        <xsl:value-of select="@extension.name" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="@extension.length" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

For this to work, you must be in the context of the referenced attributes' parent element.

---

Note also that `extention` is not the same thing as `extension`.

Comment: so how do I go about doing this.  Those attributes are pre-determined by a program so as far as I know I cant change them.  I am putting this in a table.  You want me to put this at the start of the table?

Comment: @AlexW I'm afraid  cannot help you any further without seeing a [mcve].

Comment: alright thanks for the help.  The error had to do with the extention/extension.