# How to delete a subset of the same attribute within the entire document in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to delete a **subset** of an attribute throughout the entire the document during XSLT processing. In the following XML example, I want to delete the `@id` attribute when it contains only numbers.  For the rest of `@id`, they are not changed.

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="recursion2.xsl" ?>

<list>
    <book id="B1">
        <label>1</label>
        <title id="1">A Good Story</title>
        <author>James Soul</author>
    </book>
    <book id="B2">
        <label>2</label>
        <title id="21">The Perfect Storm</title>
        <author>Laura Smith</author>
    </book>
    <journal id="J1">
        <label>3</label>
        <citation id="3">Tom Lane. The smart computation method. 2003;23(5):123-128.</citation>
    </journal>
    <journal id="J2">
        <label>4</label>
        <citation id="122">Luna Shen. The identification of new gene, SMACT4. 2010;10(2):23-38. </citation>
    </journal>
</list>
```

The expected outcome should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="recursion2.xsl" ?>
<list>
<book id="B1">
    <label>1</label>
    <title>A Good Story</title>
    <author>James Soul</author>
</book>
<book id="B2">
    <label>2</label>
    <title>The Perfect Storm</title>
    <author>Laura Smith</author>
</book>
<journal id="J1">
    <label>3</label>
    <citation>Tom Lane. The smart computation method. 2003;23(5):123-128.</citation>
</journal>
<journal id="J2">
    <label>4</label>
    <citation>Luna Shen. The identification of new gene, SMACT4. 2010;10(2):23-38. </citation>
</journal>
</list>
```

I tried the following code and thinking that `test="number(@id)=@id"` would select `@id` containing numbers only, but all the `@id` were deleted.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@id">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template>
      <xsl:if test="number(@id)=@id"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I also tried this code `<xsl:template match="@id[not(starts-with(@id, NaN))]" />`, which does not do anything

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the below template which will process the `@id` only if the value is not a number.

```
<xsl:template match="@id">
    <xsl:if test="not(number(.))">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Complete XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@id">
        <xsl:if test="not(number(.))">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<list>
    <book id="B1">
        <label>1</label>
        <title>A Good Story</title>
        <author>James Soul</author>
    </book>
    <book id="B2">
        <label>2</label>
        <title>The Perfect Storm</title>
        <author>Laura Smith</author>
    </book>
    <journal id="J1">
        <label>3</label>
        <citation>Tom Lane. The smart computation method. 2003;23(5):123-128.</citation>
    </journal>
    <journal id="J2">
        <label>4</label>
        <citation>Luna Shen. The identification of new gene, SMACT4. 2010;10(2):23-38. </citation>
    </journal>
</list>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the hint of [this post about testing the first character of attributes to be a non-numeric value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5986090/4735838), I figured out the solution I want:

```
<xsl:template match="@id[string(number(substring(.,1,1))) !='NaN']" />
```

This code will delete all `@id` started with a numeric value, which is good enough for my need. The original post has all the nice explanations.

Comment: If you are matching on the `id` attribute, as you do, inside the predicate you can simply use `.` to work with that matched attribute so instead of `substring(../@id,1,1)` you simply want `substring(., 1, 1)`.

Comment: Martin, you are absolutely right.  I will update the code above.