# Remove Anything that starts from any digit in excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have to remove anything from the cell values that start from any digit(0-9). For example cell A1 have the values: afhd21ffh, 126467, hgdasj12jg, 86589, 0186253 the output should be afhd21ffh, hgdasj12jg.

I have searched alot and tried to find the solution but couldn't get the effective one.

Comment: If a single cell (`A1`) has multiple values delimited by a comma, you could  use the `Split()` function to separate the values into an array, then remove any value that starts with a number (this is assuming some values may be `123Abc` for example)?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you provide some examples of your sheet data and what you have tried already.

Comment: There will not be any value in pattern of 123ABC, everythin will be either alphanumeric starting from alphabet(ie. BH1243) or it will be numbers like (638793443). I just want to remove anything starts from (0-9)

Comment: Please some one help me as I am not so good with the VBA

Comment: Do you prefer a VBA formula or an excel formula?

Comment: I prefer excel formula

Comment: But if its only possible by VBA then i can consider that too.

Comment: @NavneetSingh, Explain me more about **Remove**. If Column A is the Data and Column B the Result. Do you wish to List anything beginning with a Digit only on Column B. Or you want to remove completely all those cells on Column A without the need of B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use TEXTJOIN+FILTERXML function of which TEXTJOIN() available in Office 365

In `B1`, enter array formula (Ctrl+shift+Enter) :

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[.*0!=0]"))
```

[image]

Comment: I applaud the solution, but would this check the whole node? Either way, credited your answer! Always good on the `XPATH`!

Comment: This Worked for me. Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

Below is a small VBA proc that takes the contents of cell A1, and removes any values that start with a number, handling the leading space for each value, before outputting it back to the worksheet:

```
Sub sRemoveNumbers()
    Dim aData() As String
    Dim lngLoop As Long
    Dim strOutput As String
    aData() = Split(Range("A1").Value, ",")
    For lngLoop = LBound(aData) To UBound(aData)
        If IsNumeric(Left(Trim(aData(lngLoop)), 1)) = False Then
            strOutput = strOutput & aData(lngLoop) & ","
        End If
    Next lngLoop
    If Right(strOutput, 1) = "," Then strOutput = Left(strOutput, Len(strOutput) - 1)
    If Left(strOutput, 1) = "," Then strOutput = Mid(strOutput, 2)
    Range("A2") = strOutput
End Sub
```

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

A rather complicated formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",1,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[not(number(substring(.,1,1)+1))]"))
```

***Result:***

[image]

---

`"//s[not(number(substring(.,1,1)+1))]"` literally takes a substring of all nodes from the 1st position from the left and checks if this is not a number when we add 1 to it. This `XPATH 1.0` solution is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5986973/9758194)

> **Note:** It's an array formula and needs to be confirmed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: I am not getting the output as expected. Can you try for these inputs: B07Tdg531Q,B07hsf531Q,0412285277

Comment: Remember there is no space after the coma

Comment: @Navneet, there were spaces in your sample data, so I included that in the answer. We can simply change that to no spaces...I also included `substring` within the XPATH to check the left most character to include node or not.